# django: How to add extra field to all items in queryset

Tags: django

My models looks this way

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    test_plan = models.FK(TestPlan)

class TestPlan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Result(models.Model):
    user = models.FK(User)
    test_plan = models.FK(TestPlan)
    test = models.FK(Test)
    result = models.Boolean()
```

In the case I have a plan object in my view, I can access all tests by doing plan.test_set.all(). But is there a way to append all existing results to that query (so a result object is attached to a given test case, if it exists).

=====

I am trying to run the following

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     task = get_object_or_404(Plan, id=kwargs.get('id'))
     return render(request, self.template_name,
            {"task": task})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.POST
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, id=kwargs.get('id'))
    tc = get_object_or_404(Test, id=data.get('tc_id'))
    tc_result, _ = Result.objects\
          .get_or_create(task=task, test=tc,
                           result=data.get('tc_result_status'))
    return HttpResponse("OK")

And in template:
{% for test in task.tests_set.all %}
{{ test }}(here I want to render test result, if it I have one for given test in given plan, for current user)
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: are you looking for a way to save the database query? if so, look at `select_related` or `prefetch_related`

Comment: I don't see how select related can work in my case.

Comment: Can you provide an example/imaginary code you want to run?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to access a reverse one to many relationship? Just iterate in the same way you accessed `tests_set`.

```
{% for test in task.tests_set.all %}
    {{ test }} 
    {% for result in test.result_set.all %}
       {{ result }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Well the thing which confuses me is that, I want to iterate not all results for current test, but a filter them e.g. in view I would do filtering .filter(test=this_test, user=this_user, test_plan=this_plan)

Answer (score 1):

To filter the results in `task.tests_set.all()` or `test.result_set.all()` you need to use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with custom [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#prefetch-objects) object.

Something like:

```
task = get_object_or_404(
    TestPlan.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('test_set', queryset=Test.objects.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('result_set', queryset=Result.objects.filter(user=request.user))
        ))
    ),
    id=kwargs.get('id')
)
```

And in template:

```
{% for test in task.test_set.all %}
    {% for result in test.result_set.all %}
        {{ result }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```